# Does MySQL WHERE conditions regard brackets the same as PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, operators, conditional-statements

Does MySQL regard brackets in the WHERE conditions at all? Does it work like PHP where

```
WHERE (condition1 OR condition2) AND condition3
```

is the same as

```
if ((condition1 || condition2) && condition3)
```

Comment: yes, as far as i know, they are similar.

Comment: Fore more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/operator-precedence.html

Comment: Obviously yes... It won't varies per language...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that will work. I for example had something similar to this query in a project:

```
SELECT * FROM translation WHERE (language='en' AND translation_label='lbl_submit') OR (language='en' AND translation_label='lbl_submit_btn')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are calculated in the same way, although I'm not sure if in the same order.